# {related_entries} does not work after upgraded from v2.2.2 to 2.11.5

Tags: entries

```
{if related_blog_post_1 != "0"}
                <div class="relatedPosts">
                    <h3>If you enjoyed this post, you may also like:</h3>
                    <ul>
                    {related_entries id="related_blog_post_1"}
                        <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                    {/related_entries}
                    {if related_blog_post_2 != "0"}
                    {related_entries id="related_blog_post_2"}
                        <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                    {/related_entries}
                    {/if}
                    {if related_blog_post_3 != "0"}
                    {related_entries id="related_blog_post_3"}
                        <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                    {/related_entries}
                    {/if}
                    {if related_blog_post_4 != "0"}
                    {related_entries id="related_blog_post_4"}
                        <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                    {/related_entries}
                    {/if}
                    {if related_blog_post_5 != "0"}
                    {related_entries id="related_blog_post_5"}
                        <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                    {/related_entries}
                    {/if}
                    </ul>
                </div>
{/if}


{if series_blog_post_1 != "0"}
            <div class="seriesPosts">
                <h3>Series Contents:</h3>
                <ul>
                {related_entries id="series_blog_post_1"}
                    <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                {/related_entries}
                {if series_blog_post_2 != "0"}
                {related_entries id="series_blog_post_2"}
                    <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                {/related_entries}
                {/if}
                {if series_blog_post_3 != "0"}
                {related_entries id="series_blog_post_3"}
                    <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                {/related_entries}
                {/if}
                {if series_blog_post_4 != "0"}
                {related_entries id="series_blog_post_4"}
                    <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                {/related_entries}
                {/if}
                {if series_blog_post_5 != "0"}
                {related_entries id="series_blog_post_5"}
                    <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
                {/related_entries}
                {/if}
                </ul>
            </div>
            {/if}
```

Could some please help me fix this code? Or point me to the right reference for this? This {related_entries} does not work anymore. I have tried to look at 2.11.5 docs but have not found anything that could helped me yet.

Comment: I suggest you first take a look here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/relationships.html
Are these related blogposts made by a relationship field?
Are these entries in the same channel?
If you look at the examples you'll see you have either a child or a parent related entry. Can you specify your channels etc?
Also, you'll need to prefix the related entries like {related_entries}{related_entries:title}{/related_entries}

Comment: It appears that EE changed the behaviour of relationships sometime between 2.4 and 2.11 - if you look at the EE 2.4 documentation it includes a description of the `{related_entries}` tag as a thing (http://agentdir.com/modules/channel/relationships.html).  By 2.11 this has disappeared, and relationships have become more general - so rather than using `{related_entries id="name_of_relationship_field"}` at the start and end of the tag, you simply use `{name_of_relationship_field}`.  HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys.

The reason is because from version 2.6.0 I believe EE changed the **relationship** field to **relationships**. So all I had to do was to change these fields to the new compatible field.

Plus, the syntax also changed a little bit:

Ex:

before:

```
  {related_entries id="series_blog_post_1"}
      <li><a href="{title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{title}</a></li>
  {/related_entries}
```

after:

```
 {related_blog_post_1}
     <li><a href="{related_blog_post_1:title_permalink='about/blog-post'}">{related_blog_post_1:title}</a></li>
 {/related_blog_post_1}
```

The good thing is now I can do multiple relations. So instead of creating 5 related blog post fields, I can just create one and select as many related blog posts as I want.